# Is it important who submits the paper to the journal?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I'm a PhD student in computer engineering and I have recently finished writing and editing a paper under the supervision of my professor. Now it is ready to be submitted to a journal. We have chosen an Elsevier journal. Since my professor seems to be busy, I've decided to submit the paper myself. Now my question is that:

> Is there any difference between submitting the paper myself or my
>   professor? I mean if my professor submits the paper, is it better and
>   may have a better influence on reviewer?

The paper contains the names of both of us (my professor and I), I just want to know if it is important who submits the paper (ant does the submission related tasks).

If it is not important, I don't want to waste the time and I want to submit the paper ASAP. Otherwise, I should wait until my professor find the enough time to submit the paper.

Comment: In my fields (pure mathematics and theoretical computer science) it makes no difference who submits the paper. I expect that it's similar in computer engineering. But some discussions on this web site have shown me that there are fields that attach importance to being the "corresponding author" (which to me just means the one who handles correspondence with the journal but in other fields may mean more).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't really matter who submits it, since it's just an administrative procedure.

What matters is that the authors and co-authors are properly listed in both the manuscript and the submission system.

In every submission system I ever used, you have to define who is the main author and who are the co-authors, and there's usually an option to register their contact/email address so they can receive updates on the status of the procedure.

Answer (score 4):

It is common for more junior researchers to submit papers, since the submission procedure is an administrative procedure which more senior researchers don't want the burden of. Before submission, it should be agreed upon where to submit. It is also useful to establish which authors want to be included email communication, if supported by the venue.

Comment: We have agreed on where to send the paper, I was just hesitant about who should submit the paper. So it is not considered a negative point if the student submits the paper instead of the professor?